# Labelling minor and major streets for entire city on layout using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, layouts, road

I've been trying to create an ArcMap layout which shows intersections in a given city alongside the names of minor and major streets. Currently, I have the intersections properly placed and I have a road centerline which I've dissolved to create the route names. 
 The issue I'm experiencing is that when I go to label the minor and major streets using the Maplex label engine and print the layout (shown below), the labels come out much larger then anything else on the map. The only elements that show up at the correct scale (the highway labels) are ones I added via the Draw toolbar.

How could I avoid this behavior?

The settings I used for both Maplex and the layout view are shown below if that helps.

[image: Intersection Map of City]

**Layout Settings:**

[image: Page & Print Setup]

Page Size: ISO A4 Landscape

**Maplex Settings**
[image: Minor Roads]
Stacked labels, Overrun features, Reduce font size, Remove Duplicates, Repeat Label & Label buffer at 15% used.

[image]
Same settings for minor roads aside from positioning and font size/decoration.

Comment: Did you use a reference scale in that data frame ?, did you try without checking the 'scale map element' in the 'page and print setup' ?

Comment: I didn't use a reference scale and when I unchecked that box, the output was still the same.